# How to delete an image in array of images in javascript while maintaining current image list on browser screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

I have an array of images that I uploaded to the browsers screen as follows:

...

```
<input type="file" id="image" accept="image/*" name="image[]" multiple /><br/>
<div id="images"></div>
    
$('#image').change(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < $(this)[0].files.length; i++) {
      imageCount = imageCount + 1;
        $("#images").append('<div style="width:100px;"><img src="'+window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[i])+'" id="images" width="100px" height="100px"/>'+'<button type="button" onclick="uploadImage('+imageCount+');">Upload </button>&nbsp;<button type="button" onclick="removeImage('+imageCount +');">X</button></div>   nbsp;');

    }
});

function removeImage(position) {
     images = $('#images');
     alert("Position: "+position);
}
```

...

How would one go about removing an image at a specific position in the image array?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has nothing to do with [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Instead, you're trying to add / remove elements from the DOM. Rather than trying to dynamically assign values to `onclick`, you can just use an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

Also good to note, with your code you will end up with multiple elements having `id="image"`, which is invalid. [IDs need to be unique.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp)  Instead, use [classes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp). See also [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
<input type="file" id="add_images" accept="image/*" multiple />
<div id="images"></div>

$('#add_images').on('change', function(){
  $.each(this.files, function(file) {
    $('#images').append(`
      <div style="width:100px;">
        <img class="image" src="${window.URL.createObjectURL(file)}">
        <button class="upload_image">Upload</button>
        <button class="remove_image">X</button>
      </div>`);
  });
});

$('#images') //this replaces the onclick="" method
  .on('click', 'button.remove_image', function() {
    this.parentElement.remove();
  });
  .on('click', 'button.upload_image', function() {
    //code for uploading image
  });
```

Can't say I've ever used [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), so you may need to rejigger that part of the code.

Comment: Your code is mostly working, though $(this).parent().remove(); would have worked better for removing the element that I was trying to remove. 

My question is, how would I access the image that was temporary uploaded to the browser?

Comment: Whoops, you're right, it should be the parent removed, I'll fix that. You could do it the way you were attempting to do it, give each image a unique identifier, then access it using that. But that can run into challenges with the `unique` part. Or the way that I'm suggestion, which uses a parent element and DOM traversal to make the buttons relative to the image, no identifiers required. Search `DOM traversal`. Are you trying to do more than upload / remove?

Comment: I'm just trying to work on upload and remove for now.